# Integral of $\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1-x} 1_{[0,\alpha]}(x)$ and series with positive terms

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Sorry for my bad english.

We consider $f_{\alpha} : R \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ defined by $f_{\alpha}(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1-x} \mathbb{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(x)$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$.

We want to write the integral $\int_{R} f_{\alpha} d \lambda$ as a sum of series with positives terms.

I really don't know how to do it ! I thought to write the function in the form $$\dfrac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x}\times\sqrt{|x|}$$ but without success.

Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't t easier to write $\int_{0}^{\alpha}{\,\sqrt{\,x\,}\, \over 1 - x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ with $\alpha \in \left(\,{0,1}\,\right)$ ?. It's quite readable !!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty  x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}, \qquad |x|<1,
$$ then one is allowed to write, for $0\le\alpha<1$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{\alpha}(x) d \lambda = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1-x} \mathbb{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(x)\:dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{0}^\alpha x^n\sqrt{|x|}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^{n+3/2}}{n+3/2}.
$$

Comment: @MélanieDelaCheminée You are welcome.

Comment: Toujours aussi efficace, je ne m'en lasse pas :)

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha=0$, then $f_0(0)=1$ and $f_0(x)=0$ for $x \ne 0$.

Let $ \alpha >0$. Then:

$f_{\alpha}(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{1-x}$ for $x \in [0, \alpha]$ and $f_{\alpha}(x) =0$ for $x \in \mathbb R \setminus [0, \alpha]$